# Does a resistor slow down the speed of current or cause voltage drop or both?

Tags: voltage, current, resistors

I want to know whether a resistor slows down the speed of current or cause a voltage drop or both simultaneously.

Comment: To put it in a way as broadly applicable as possible, a resistor sets a proportionality constant between current and voltage.

Comment: The proper name for "speed of current" is *electron drift velocity*, and it doesn't figure in circuit analysis. Are you sure you are talking about drift velocity, or about something else?

Comment: It doesn't slow down the speed of current. It causes voltage drop according to Ohm's law for resistors ( V = I x R).

Comment: A resistor will reduce the amount of current, not slow it down.

Comment: If "slows down the speed of current" is supposed to mean "reduces the current" then this question would make sense as a beginner question.

Answer (score 1):

It may depend on what you mean by the "speed" of a current.

The electric field that pushes electrons around travels at something close to the speed of light.  The actual speed depends on the physical characteristics of each conductor in a circuit.

The "drift velocity" is the average speed of any electron in the circuit. The electrons bounce around randomly, very rapidly.  But if you apply an electric field, they start to bounce a bit more often in the direction of that field.  If you reduce the current, then the drift velocity goes down accordingly.

The number of electrons per second going round the circuit is the current, by definition.  One amp is one coulomb worth of electrons per second.

---

In any case, because of Ohm's law, reducing the voltage (for example by dropping voltage across a resistor), reduces current, and reducing current reduces voltage.  They go together.

Comment: Has it not been established that electrons do no flow through a circuit, they exchange electromagnetic energy?

Comment: @ejbpesca established by whom?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a link to the YouTube explanation of how electrical energy flows through a circuit.  It is a theory I thought had become accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The drift velocity of an electric current in a metallic conductor is related to the quantity of current by the formula

$$I = n_eAv_d$$

Where \$n_e\$ is the number of free/conduction electrons per unit volume, \$A\$ is the cross sectional area of the wire, and \$v_d\$ is is the drift velocity.

> Does a resistor slow down the speed of current

From the above formula, it should be clear that unless we know the cross-sectional area of the conductive part of a resistor, and also the free electrons density, compared to the values of those parameters in other parts of the circuit, we cannot know whether the drift velocity will be higher in the resistor as compared to other parts of the circuit, or lower.

Let's assume, for a moment, that the body of a resistor just consists of a coiled length of very thin wire (a wire-wound resistor). And further assume that the wire is either of the same type as the other wires in the circuit (just a different diameter), or, if the wire is made from a different substance, at least has the same number of free electrons per unit volume.

What happens to the drift velocity of the electric current as the current enters the resistor. Does it decrease? No, it *increases*! This is exactly analogous to what happens so often to a wide river when it comes to a narrow gorge. When it reaches the narrowing, the current speeds up. And this is true, in part because water is virtually incompressible. The incompressibility if water in our analogy corresponds to our assumption that the density of free electrons is the same in the resistor as in the wire leads to the resistor.

It is also worth considering what happens to the velocity of a river current after it *leaves* a gorge, and enters a wide channel. Typically it will slow down. Likewise with the drift velocity of an electric current if the wire carrying that current changes from a smaller cross sectional area to a larger cross sectional area. In our assumed wire-wound resistor, the drift velocity of the current will decrease as the current leaves the resistor.

> Does a resistor ... cause [a] voltage drop?

Yes. And the voltage drop across the resistor is given by Ohm's Law

$$V =IR$$

The larger the current passing through a given resistance, the larger the voltage difference between the two sides of the resistor. The larger the resistor that a given current passes through, the larger the voltage difference between the two sides of the resistor.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of electric current is the rate of flow of electric charge:
$$i=\frac{dq}{dt}$$

The current can be expanded to include linear charge density \$\lambda\$ and velocity \$v\$ of the charges:
$$i=\frac{dq}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=\lambda v$$

If the current is supplied from a voltage source \$E\$ and the resistance has a value of \$R\$, then the charge will flow through the resistor with a current \$\lambda v\$.

If \$R\$ is increased, then the current will decrease. So either the charge density decreases or the velocity will decrease. In a typical resistor, the charge density will remain constant, so the velocity of the charges will decrease.

If the current is supplied from a current source \$E\$ and the resistance has a value of \$R\$, then the charge will flow through the resistor with a current \$\lambda v\$ as before.

Now, if \$R\$ is increased, then the current will remain the same. The voltage \$E\$ will increase. So both the charge density and the velocity will remain the same.

Now for a wrinkle. If a current source is connected with a thick wire in series with a thin wire, the resistance increases as the charge flows from the thick wire to the thin wire. The linear charge density decreases as the charge flows from the thick wire to the thin wire, so the velocity must increase to maintain the constant current. We see this when watering the lawn. To increase the speed of the water the opening is restricted increasing the resistance.

The speed of the current is the speed of the charge, care must be taken with conventional current. Two cases above show that resistance can cause the current to slow down or remain the same speed. In the third case, the current remains the same but the charge velocity increases as the charge density decreases.

> Does a resistor cause a voltage drop.

The free electrons flowing though the resistance bounce from the lattice with a force that opposes the direction of flow. This reaction force ultimately produces a reaction voltage that opposes the applied voltage. We call this reaction voltage the voltage drop. The charge flowing through the lattice creates this voltage. Without it the current speed would continue to increase. When the voltage drop is the same magnitude as the applied voltage, the current remains constant. This allows of KVL to work. In a sense the voltage doesn't drop, but an opposing voltage is created.

Yes, the resistance can do both simultaneously.